# How does Spell Mastery work exactly?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

Could someone clarify this feat a bit?  Does it mean that you can cast those "mastered" spells an unlimited amount of times per day or is it more like "oh I didn't have that 1 hour to prepare my spellbook/I lost my spellbook but I can still cast these."

Also, can this feat be taken more than once?  It seems to imply it can be but I didn't see that explicitly stated anywhere. A source for this would be great, thanks!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Benefit: Each time you take this feat, choose a number of spells that you already know equal to your Intelligence modifier. From that point on, you can prepare these spells without referring to a spellbook. [Source (SRD)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-mastery---final)

The only benefit Spell Mastery gives you is the ability to prepare a selected number of spells without access to your spellbook. You still need to spend the usual time to prepare spells.

"Each time you take this feat" implies you may take the feat more than once, and again select a number of spells you know equal to you intelligence modifier.

It is worth noting that in Pathfinder benefits from your ability modifiers are *retroactive*, so if you take the feat at an Int bonus of +2, level up and increase it to +3, You may choose 1 more spell as per the feat. If you were to then take the feat again you would choose another three and hence be able to prepare a total of 6 (specific) spells without your spellbook on hand.

Comment: Is it true to say that this is only really useful if you lose your spell book, or does it make a difference even with spell book in hand? For instance, does it mean that the spells prepared with this feat do not take up spell slots or something?

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter I'm sure those more creative than I could think of more uses, but yes it seems to me it's main focus is providing access to spells in situations where you don't have your spellbook, (Lost, imprisoned, etc.)